# Clojure - how to build up a data structure, possibly incrementally

Tags: collections, clojure

New to Clojure.

I am trying to build up a data structure programmatically for insertion into a database.  I actually have something that works just fine, but it does an insert for each record, and I'd like to generate the whole record, and then insert the whole thing at once with one insert.

Here is what I have working so far:

```
  (doseq [record-data1 [:one :two :three]
    (doseq [record-data2 [1 2 3]]
      (insert {record-data1 record-data2})
```

Any suggestions on how to generate the entire bulk structure first before insert?  Have tried variations on map, walk, etc. but haven't been able to come up with anything yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want the "entire bulk structure" to look like?

Comment: whoops, you are right.  something like this: ({:one 1} {:one 2} {:one 3} {:two 1} ... )

Comment: If you require to add every combination of two collections, I'd be concerned about the database design. Ought the table to be factored into two?

Comment: @Thumbnail, no.  The collections are just a way to generate the records I need.  The table is properly factored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "entire bulk structure".  You can't put the cross-product of record-data1 and record-data2 in the same dictionary.  Maybe you're looking for this:

```
user=> (for [record-data1 [:a :b :c] record-data2 [1 2 3]] {record-data1 record-data2})
({:a 1} {:a 2} {:a 3} {:b 1} {:b 2} {:b 3} {:c 1} {:c 2} {:c 3})
```

Comment: i think this is exactly what i'm looking for - thanks.  one of the challenges of learning a new language is simply learning all the functions possible in the standard library.  point being, i didn't know "for" existed.

Comment: You can also use extra bindings on `doseq` to get the same expansion behavior that `for` has (though in this case you don't want that because you want a single insert statement).